# Using PyQt4 - QTableView with SQLAlchemy using QSqlTableModel (or not)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyqt4

i'm starting to learn Qt for python and as i was wondering after reading this post :
[qt - pyqt QTableView not populating when changing databases.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659756/qt-pyqt-qtableview-not-populating-when-changing-databases) if there was a way to use SQLAlchemy sessions instead of (re-)opening a database connection as a Table Model with Qt's QTableView widget.

Something that would work a little bit like that :

```
databasePath = "base.sqlite" # used for production

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + databasePath, echo=True)

# initializing session :
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Set up the user interface from Designer.
self.setupUi(self)

self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
self.model.setTable("records")

self.model.setSort(FILEORDER, Qt.AscendingOrder)

self.model.setHeaderData(ID, Qt.Horizontal, QVariant("ID"))
self.model.setHeaderData(NAME, Qt.Horizontal, QVariant("Name"))
self.model.select()

self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as well as new ways to think about this problem.

Thank you

Comment: well i guess i'll start working on that then

Comment: Very interesting question :)

Although it would be great if you could somehow combine PyQt4's classes with other classes, this is not possible as far as I know. Although you could try emulating a QSqlDatabase with SQLAlchemy, I would think it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: well i'll just try to create a new model one could use just giving the SQLAlchemy session as parameter (and maybe the ORM's Classes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/) . It does much more:)

I happily found it when the frustration and angst, generated by Q*View and Q*Model experience forced me to start implementing my own ones on the basis of SqlAlchemy. And it was half implemented, when I found the instrument, that does much more, than I've even dream of, struggling with QSqlRelationalTableModel.